# Include external javascript file in header navbar file not found

Tags: javascript, php, include, structure, external

I have the following folder structure:

- website.com/index.php
- website.com/page/asd.php
- website.com/header.php
- website.com/js/file.js

header.php contains:

```
<script src="js/file.js"></script>
```

index.php contains:

```
include_once 'header.php';
```

asd.php contains:

```
include_once  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/header.php';
```

So file.js will work on index.php, but file.js doesnt work on asd.php.
On asd.php the browser want to get **/pages/js/file.js** (which doesnt exist) and not **/js/file.js**

How can I handle this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start path of your file with `/`

```
<script src="/js/file.js"></script>
```

This will tell browser to look from the root directory.